# Vector derivative in a unitary normal vector dependent function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vectors, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

I am struggling in finding the paratial vector derivative of a function of a unitary normal vector of the form $E=\bf{\hat{n}}\cdot\bf{\hat{v}} = \hat{n}^T\hat{v}$. Lets say we have $\bf{r_1}$,  $\bf{r_2}$ and  $\bf{r_3}$ column-vectors and  $\bf{\hat{n}} = \frac{(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times (\bf{r_2 - r_1})}{|(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times (\bf{r_2 - r_1})|}$. $\bf{\hat{v}}$ is other unitary column  vector that is not relevant until the end.

The partial derivative with respecto $\bf{r_1}$ would be given by $\partial_\bf{r_1} = \partial_\bf{r_1}\bf{\hat{n}}\bf{\hat{v}}$,
where 
 
$\partial_\bf{r_1}\bf{\hat{n}} = \frac{1}{{|(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times (\bf{r_2 - r_1})|}}\partial_\bf{r_1}(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times(\bf{r_2 - r_1}) + (\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times(\bf{r_2 - r_1})\frac{\partial_\bf{r_1}}{{|(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times (\bf{r_2 - r_1})|}}$. 
By consideringthe skew-symmetric matrix $\bf{a} \times \bf{b}  = [\bf{a}]_xb = [\bf{b}]_xa$,and then, if $\bf{a = a(r_1)}$ and $\bf{b = b(r_1)}$,
$\bf\partial_{r1} = [a]_x(\partial_{r_1}b) - [b]_x(\partial_{r_1}a)$. 
Consequently, $\partial_\bf{r_1}(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times(\bf{r_2 - r_1}) = [r_3 - r_2]_x$. My problem comes later, when finding the derivative in the modulus, 
$\frac{\partial_\bf{r_1}}{{|(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times (\bf{r_2 - r_1})|}} = - \frac{(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times (\bf{r_2 - r_1})}{|(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times (\bf{r_2 - r_1})|^3}[\bf{r_3-r_2}]_x = \frac{(\bf{r_3 - r_2})\times[(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times (\bf{r_2 - r_1})]^T}{|(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times (\bf{r_2 - r_1})|^3}$  
where in the last equality I have transposed the numerator to convert the skew to a cross product. The transpose in the second cross produdct is kept for clarity. My main problem is in the evaluation  
$(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times(\bf{r_2 - r_1})\frac{\partial_\bf{r_1}}{{|(\bf{r_3 - r_1})\times (\bf{r_2 - r_1})|}}$. 

I think that the transposition leads to a row vector, such that the previous product results in a matrix. Without transposition the dimensions does not agree. I find this confusing. Finally the multiplication by $\bf\hat{v}$ leads to a vector as it is expected from the vector derivative of a scalar.

Can someone clarify me the problem or show me where are my mistakes?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of typing let's use $\{x,y,z\}$ in place of $\{r_1,r_2,r_3\}$.

And $(a,b)$ for the differences instead of $\{(z-x),\,(y-x)\}$.

The vector we wish to analyze is $(a\times b)$.
$$\eqalign{
p &= a\times b &\implies dp = a\times db - b\times da \\
\lambda^2 &= p\cdot p &\implies \lambda\,d\lambda = p\cdot dp,\;
\lambda=\|p\| \\
n &= \lambda^{-1}p &\implies d\lambda=n\cdot dp,\quad
{\tt 1}=\|n\| \\
}$$
Dot an arbitrary vector with $dp$ and recall the triple scalar product rule:
$\;c\cdot(a\times b) = (c\times a)\cdot b$ 
$$\eqalign{
y\cdot dp
 &= y\cdot(a\times db) - y\cdot(b\times da) \\
 &= (y\times a)\cdot db - (y\times b)\cdot da \\
 &= (Ya)\cdot db - (Yb)\cdot da \\
 &= Y\,(a\cdot db - b\cdot da) \\
}$$
where the uppercase letter $\{Y\}$ denotes the skew symmetric cross-product matrix for $y$.

Now we're ready to tackle the derivative of the ${\cal E}$ function.
$$\eqalign{
{\cal E} &= v\cdot n = \lambda^{-1}\;v\cdot p \\
d{\cal E} &= \lambda^{-1}\;v\cdot dp - \lambda^{-2}d\lambda\;v\cdot p \\
 &= \lambda^{-1}\;(v\cdot dp - {\cal E}\,d\lambda) \\
 &= \lambda^{-1}\;(v\cdot dp-{\cal E}n\cdot dp) \\
 &= \lambda^{-1}\;(v-{\cal E}n)\cdot dp \\
 &= \lambda^{-1}\;(V-{\cal E}N)\,(a\cdot db - b\cdot da) \\
}$$

If $\{y,z\}$ are held constant we can substitute $\;da=db=-dx\;$ 
$$\eqalign{
d{\cal E}
 &= \lambda^{-1}\,(V-{\cal E}N)(b-a)\cdot dx \\
 &= \lambda^{-1}\,(v-{\cal E}n)\times(y-z)\cdot dx \\
\frac{\partial{\cal E}}{\partial x}
 &= \lambda^{-1}\,(v-{\cal E}n)\times(y-z) \\
}$$
Conversely, if we hold $\{x,z\}$ constant, then $\,da=0,\,db=dy$.

While holding $\{x,y\}$ constant means $\;da=dz,\,db=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you so much greg, your answer is brilliant. Very much appreciated. I think your answer is very elegant and less prone to mistakes than  the procedure I was following. I specially liked the independent and unique $db$ and $da$ factors, such that one can now derivate with respect to $x,y,z$ in a very direct manner without going through all the process again. 
  Just two additional questions: 
 1) $\lambda$ stands for the square of the module of the cross product and thus, would not be $n = \lambda^{-1/2} p$ ? 
2) I follow your derivation but I still would like to get where are the mistakes in my scheme. I am not fluent in vector calculus and would to learn more. For instance, I was surprised with the relation $d\lambda = n\cdot dp$ since the way you extracted the differential of the modulus here is not intuitive to me. From a didactic perspective is good to me to get the errors even if I can use your recipe.

Comment: Sorry, point one is clear. I did not read it properly

Comment: The problem with your initial scheme is that it's hard to manipulate (differentiate) complicated quantities like $\|(r_3-r_1)\times(r_2-r_1)\|$ versus simple symbols like $p$ and $\lambda$. If you do it carefully you of course will obtain the same result, but it's _mentally taxing_ since there are so many rules, i.e. differentiating quotients, cross products, and moduli, distributing the cross product over a sum, etc,

Comment: Yes, is true that is quite tough not to do mistakes and what finally leads to my feeling of uncertainty, specially considering the relevance of keeping the tract of the transpositions.  <br> By the way, given  that $\lambda = n\cot p$ why the differential is not $d\lambda = dn\cdot p + p\cdot dn$? In the end both $n$ and $p$ are functions of ${x,y,z}$

Comment: On my previous question: $\lambda = n \cdot p$. Then $\lambda = |n||p|\cos(\theta)$ but since $n$ and $p$ of course share orientation $\lambda = |n||p| = |p|$ and then $d\lambda = d|p| = \frac{p}{\lambda}dp = n \cdot dp$. <br><br> I see that but not so why $d\lambda = dn\cdot p + n\cdot dp$ does not match unless $dn$ = 0

Comment: You've just discovered on of the many weird identities of vector calculus: The derivative of a unit vector is always _perpendicular_ to the unit vector. In other words, it can only change its direction, not its length. BTW, I didn't state it as a given, I simply divided the line preceeding it by $\lambda$.

Comment: That is very true greg, very nice point on that you obtained just by dividing by $\lambda$. Thanks again for all your explanations, much appreciated